# background service call inside for loop in java?

Tags: java, for-loop, background-service

I hope I can explain the problem in proper way :)
I have an array of object (handleData).I get them from DB. I want to send them  to server by calling service for each one individually. 
I put the service in a for loop to send all handleData (refer to code) .

Calling service is done a background . the response of each may not come as they sent orderly. and I have to do some update for each handleData I send.

problem : when the response comes I am not sure that if the regarded action (update of record) is done to the exact handleData that I want/sent properly.

```
private void sendDataOfTemplates() {
    ArrayList<FormHandleData> formHandleDatas = FormHandleData.getDatasFromDB(getContext(), 12, EnumDataStatusOfServer.NoSTATUS.getIntValue(),-1);// true means >> to send / -1 means no limit
    try {
        if (formHandleDatas != null && formHandleDatas.size() != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < formHandleDatas.size(); i++) {
                final FormHandleData handleData = formHandleDatas.get(i);
                if (handleData.status_in_server == EnumDataStatusOfServer.OPEN.getIntValue())
                    if (handleData.status_in_app == EnumDataStatusInApp.SAVED.getIntValue() || handleData.status_in_app == EnumDataStatusInApp.EDITED.getIntValue()) {
                        ServiceHelper.getInstance().sendDataOfTemplates(new ServiceHelper.ResponseListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                try {

                                    SimpleResponse simple_response = new Gson().fromJson(response, SimpleResponse.class);
                                    if (simple_response.isSuccessful()) {
                                       handleData.status_in_app = EnumDataStatusInApp.SENT.getIntValue();
                                        FormHandleData.UpdateDataTemplatesInDB(handleData, getContext(),false);
                                    } else {
                                    }
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            }
                        }, handleData);
                    }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}
```

Comment: Urg. The very first thing I recommend here: go and read "clean code" by Robert Martin. Especially about the "single layer of abstraction" principle. And hint: catching Exception to then completely ignore any error, that is a **super bad** practice. You should at least **log** your errors, but most likely: do something about them.

Comment: Spaghetti code, unreadable code, etc. Please read the basics of clean code, it will help you and also those who have to see your code.

Answer (score 7):

> *problem : when the response comes I am not sure that if the regarded action (update of record) is done to the exact handleData that I want/sent properly.*

If I understand correctly, you are asking if the surrounding local variable `handleData` which is being accessed by your anonymous `ServiceHelper.ResponseListener` subclass will always be the same object instance even though in the next `for` cycle the value of that variable will be different. The answer is yes. So you don't need to worry.

If you want to know more about how anonymous classes can capture variables from a surrounding scope, please read [this part of the Oracle's Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html#accessing), which says:

> - An anonymous class has access to the members of its enclosing class.
> - An anonymous class cannot access local variables in its enclosing scope that are not declared as final or effectively final.

So the fact that the surrounding variable can be accessed means it is (effectively) final from the perspective of the anonymous class, i.e. it does not change.

Here is a little demonstration using multiple threads:

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class WhoDoesWhat {
  private String name;
  private final String action;

  public WhoDoesWhat(String name, String action) {
    this.name = name;
    this.action = action;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return name + " -> " + action;
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Application {
  private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<WhoDoesWhat> peopleDoingSomething = new ArrayList<>();
    peopleDoingSomething.add(new WhoDoesWhat("Galileo", "discover moons of Jupiter"));
    peopleDoingSomething.add(new WhoDoesWhat("Johannes", "determine the laws of planetary motion"));
    peopleDoingSomething.add(new WhoDoesWhat("Albert", "explain the precession of Mercury"));
    peopleDoingSomething.add(new WhoDoesWhat("Edwin", "notice something odd about recession speeds of galaxies"));

    for (WhoDoesWhat personDoingSomething : peopleDoingSomething) {
      new Thread(() -> {
        System.out.println("START " + personDoingSomething);
        try {
          int waitCycles = 1 + RANDOM.nextInt(10);
          for (int cycle = 0; cycle < waitCycles; cycle++) {
            System.out.println("  " + personDoingSomething.getName() + " is still being busy");
            Thread.sleep(250);
          }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        System.out.println("STOP " + personDoingSomething);
      }).start();
    }
  }
}
```

The console log could look like this:

```
START Johannes -> determine the laws of planetary motion
START Albert -> explain the precession of Mercury
START Galileo -> discover moons of Jupiter
START Edwin -> notice something odd about recession speeds of galaxies
  Albert is still being busy
  Johannes is still being busy
  Edwin is still being busy
  Galileo is still being busy
  Galileo is still being busy
  Edwin is still being busy
  Johannes is still being busy
  Albert is still being busy
  Edwin is still being busy
  Galileo is still being busy
  Albert is still being busy
STOP Johannes -> determine the laws of planetary motion
  Edwin is still being busy
  Galileo is still being busy
  Albert is still being busy
  Galileo is still being busy
STOP Edwin -> notice something odd about recession speeds of galaxies
STOP Albert -> explain the precession of Mercury
  Galileo is still being busy
  Galileo is still being busy
  Galileo is still being busy
STOP Galileo -> discover moons of Jupiter
```

Comment: @tahaGhSa, would you mind providing some feedback before the bounty period is over? Do you understand my explanation and my sample code? Do you have any follow-up questions?

Comment: As the variable is final, you'll get a reference of the same handleData that was passed. The other instances of this variable are out of scope

Comment: Isn't that what I explained and what the linked Oracle documentation also says? But please note that I did not declare `personDoingSomething` as final. It is just _effectively_ final, a fact which the Java compiler can determine.

Comment: Yes it was,, Just adding a TLDR to clarify :)

Answer (score 5):

you can send them one by one when each one is finished like recursive methods. hope this work for you..

Comment: thx for réponse,but if one item is not sent or any error occurs other item will not send.

Answer (score 0):

> problem : when the response comes I am not sure that if the regarded action (update of record) is done to the exact handleData that I want/sent properly.

I know it's an old thread but just wanna help........
In order to find out that the returning handleData corresponds to which element of formHandleDatas ArrayList, you can send an id (which is unique to each one of the elements of the array list) alongside handleData to the server and send it back to the client whenever server returns the result. In this way it will be possible to find the exact handleData. Here I have refactored your code a little bit.

```
    private void sendDataOfTemplates() {

    Map<Integer, FormHandleData> formHandleDataMap = FormHandleData.getDatasFromDBAsMap();

    try {

        if (formHandleDataMap != null && formHandleDataMap.size() != 0) {

            formHandleDataMap.forEach((key, handleData) -> {

                if (handleData.getStatusInServer() == FormHandleData.EnumDataStatusOfServer.OPEN.ordinal())
                    if (handleData.getStatusInApp() == FormHandleData.EnumDataStatusInApp.SAVED.ordinal() ||
                            handleData.getStatusInApp()== FormHandleData.EnumDataStatusInApp.EDITED.ordinal()) {

                        ServiceHelper.getInstance().sendDataOfTemplates(
                                new ServiceHelper.ResponseListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                                        try {

                                            SimpleResponse simpleResponse = new Gson().fromJson(response, SimpleResponse.class);
                                            FormHandleData currentHandleData = formHandleDataMap.get(simpleResponse.getKey());
                                            if (simpleResponse.isSuccessful()) {
                                                currentHandleData.setStatusInApp(FormHandleData.EnumDataStatusInApp.SENT.ordinal());
                                                FormHandleData.UpdateDataTemplatesInDB(currentHandleData, getContext(), false);
                                            } else {
                                                System.out.println("simple response is not successful");
                                            }
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            System.out.println("exception happened while getting simple response:" + e.getMessage());
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onErrorResponse() {
                                    }

                                }, handleData);

                    }


            });

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("exception happened:" + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

here I've used a Map to handle the unique id I mentioned, actually unique id the key of the handleData entry in the map. hope it helps.

Comment: An ID is unnecessary for the reasons I laid out in my own answer. The way anonymous or local classes work with regard to access to variables from surrounding scopes guarantees that the object used inside the anonymous class is the one which was assigned to the surrounding variable at the time the instance was created.